# color a button when is clicked

Tags: java, android, view, touch-event, ondraw

I am creating a small calculator for Android. The keyboard of the calculator is created by Java code in OnDraw:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    buttonH = height/rows;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
        Typeface tf = Typeface.create(Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager,"fonts/font.ttf"),
    Typeface.NORMAL);

    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    textSize = (width+height)/43;

    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));

    Bitmap[][] buttons = new Bitmap[rows][];
    int spacing = (width+height)/400;

    LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(buttonW/2,0,buttonW/2,buttonH,
                buttonShade,null,Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        int thisColumns = cScreen[i].length;
        buttons[i] = new Bitmap[thisColumns];
        buttonW = width/thisColumns;
        for(int j = 0; j < thisColumns; j++){

            buttons[i][j] = Bitmap.createBitmap(buttonW,buttonH,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas temp = new Canvas(buttons[i][j]);
            paint.setShader(gradient1);
            RectF rect = new RectF(spacing,spacing,buttonW-spacing,buttonH-spacing);
            temp.drawRoundRect(rect, width/100,height/100,paint);
            paint.setShader(null);
            temp.drawText(cScreen[i][j],buttonW/2,(buttonH+textSize)/2,paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(buttons[i][j], buttonW*j+shift,buttonH*i, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

but I would like to color the area of the button when the button is clicked

[image]

Comment: use drawable resource for button like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2668538/2181456 .onDraw is costlier

Comment: the button are created as bitmap not in xml

Comment: If you used transparent bitmaps for the button and drawn the background yourself it will be much easier for you IMO. and if u used normal buttons on a layout it will be even easier.

Comment: and can't i paint just the area of ​​the button in onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to color the button while it is pressed you can implement this using xml.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bg_clolor_highlight" /> 
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bg_clolor_highlight" /> 
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_clolor_normal" /> 
  </selector>
```

Otherwise you can just call .setBackgroundColor(your_color) on the button.

Comment: the button are created as bitmap not in xml

Comment: @bisssi it would be advised to create the buttons in xml. Much easier and much more maintainable. Of course if you're not doing it to learn painting in Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Create a different Paint object in onDraw for the clicked button:

```
 Paint p=new Paint(); 
 paint.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Get the coordinates of the click position on the canvas:

in constructor attach an onTouch listener()

```
float x,y;

this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
          x=event.getX();y=event.getY();
     }
});
```

in onDraw:

```
    Paint p=new Paint(); 
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    int thisColumns = cScreen[i].length;
    buttons[i] = new Bitmap[thisColumns];
    buttonW = width/thisColumns;

    for(int j = 0; j < thisColumns; j++){
        Paint tempPaint;
         if(x> buttonW*j+shift&&x< buttonW*j+shift+buttonW&&y>buttonH*i&&y<buttonH*i+buttonH) 
         tempPaint=p;
         else
         tempPaint=paint;
        buttons[i][j] = Bitmap.createBitmap(buttonW,buttonH,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas temp = new Canvas(buttons[i][j]);
        tempPaint.setShader(gradient1);
        RectF rect = new RectF(spacing,spacing,buttonW-spacing,buttonH-spacing);
        temp.drawRoundRect(rect, width/100,height/100,tempPaint);
        tempPaint.setShader(null);
        temp.drawText(cScreen[i][j],buttonW/2,(buttonH+textSize)/2,tempPaint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(buttons[i][j], buttonW*j+shift,buttonH*i, tempPaint);
    }
}
```